# Not able to tile floating windows in xmonad

Tags: xmonad

I am using xmonad.hs from https://github.com/escaped/xmonad-config. I dont see that the binding for super-t( flattens window back to tiling layer ) has been changed anywhere but when I use super-t I am not able to tile the floating windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That key binding was not changed, it was never set in the first place.

You can see in `main` that the keys are redefined to `keys = myKeys`. If you look at the definition of `myKeys`, you can see the keys of `defaultConfig` are never added, the author defined only the key bindings they wished to use.

If you want that key binding, you must add it. `keys` is a function taking an XConfig and returning the map associating keys and what they do. The author is using the `fromList` function from the `Data.Map` module to create the map from a list. You can add your key binding to the list :

```
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
           [ 
            -- List elements, separated by commas
           , ((modMask, xK_t), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)
            -- Other list elements ...
           ]
```

Relevant parts of the XMonad documentation :

- [XMonad.Config](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.14.2/docs/XMonad-Config.html) where you can look at [the source code defining `defaultConfig`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/src/XMonad-Config.html#defaultConfig) and see the other key bindings you might want to add.
- `withFocused` and `windows` are documented in [XMonad.Operation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.14.2/docs/XMonad-Operations.html) and `sink` in [XMonad.StackSet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.14.2/docs/XMonad-StackSet.html), along with other functions to manipulate windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the documentation, but `mod-shift-t` works for flattening tiled windows for default xmonad configuration.